# DataGridView not showing data VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

It's very strange, I have one grid working and showing what it needs to and two are not and they are all written the same way.

Code that works:

```
Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    access.ExecQuery("SELECT emotion1,emotion2,emotion3,emotion4,emotion5, " & _
                     "situation1,situation2,situation3, " & _
                     "physical1,physical2,physical3,physical4,physical5 " & _
                     "FROM emotionlogdb ORDER BY id DESC;")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.exception) Then
        MsgBox(access.exception) : Exit Sub
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = access.DBDT

End Sub
```

And the two codes that don't:

```
 Private Sub Form5_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    access.ExecQuery("SELECT journal FROM journalDB ORDER BY id DESC")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.exception) Then
        MsgBox(access.exception) : Exit Sub
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = access.DBDT
End Sub
```

And:

```
 Private Sub Form6_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sit As Integer = Alg.sitMode
    Dim em As Integer = Alg.emMode

    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT EmPlusSitMemo FROM TrendsDB WHERE EmotionID1= " & em & "AND SitID1= " & sit & ";")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.exception) Then
        MsgBox(Access.exception) : Exit Sub
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Access.DBDT
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i had the same issue . i think the columns of datagridview in form 5 and 6 are not added programmically . so delete the columns that you created yourself and keep the datagridview empty . actually the data is being added but you get to see only the columns that you created which is empty .

Answer (score 0):

What you need to try is to put a breakpoint at the following lines:

```
access.ExecQuery("SELECT journal FROM journalDB ORDER BY id DESC")
```

and

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT EmPlusSitMemo FROM TrendsDB WHERE EmotionID1= " & em & "AND SitID1= " & sit & ";")
```

and then run your project in Debug mode. If you are using MS Visual Studio, you need to hit F5 key. But you also need to set your solution configuration to Debug (to enable generation of debug symbols) instead of Release.

When you have started your application in debug mode generate the necessary user activity (i.e. clicking links, buttons) to get to the place where those 2 non-working, empty forms get shown. If you manage to raise the Form5_Shown or Form6_Shown events the debugger will stop at those breakpoints you have set.

Then press F10 (again if you are using Visual Stuido) and see if the SQL query to your DB executes without exceptions. Maybe you have misspelled the field name or table names.